# Preserve Variant type when copying to Range

Tags: excel, vba

Reduced to its bare essentials, this is my code:

```
Public Sub test_sub()
  Dim myVar As Variant
  myVar = "1/1"
  Range("A1") = myVar
End Sub
```

My problem is that my string "1/1" is being rendered in Excel as a date:

[image: Excel rendering]

when I want it to be displayed as just "1/1".

How could I direct Excel not to reinterpret string values when I copy a Variant array to an Range?

N.B. I know that I could prefix my string with a ` to achieve this, but in my full code I'm actually copying quite a large array to the Range, so I'm hoping there's a method which doesn't involve looping over the whole array and adding in these ticks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick and dirty, If you know the range you are going to paste the array into, you could format it as text first

```
Range("A1").NumberFormat = "@"
```

Comment: Good enough for my purposes! Thanks.